# How can I fix: Terraform error refreshing state: state snapshot was created by Terraform v0.14.5, which is newer than current v0.13.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to upgrade my terraform version from 0.12 to 0.13 but had previously init and planned with globally install terraform 0.14.5.

I'm struggling to understand how this effects the snapshot and/or I can remove this error, remote state hasn't changed so where is it getting this from? I have removed any .terraform in the directory.

Comment: What does `terraform state list` gives? If you take the latest state, what does it shows for `terraform_version`?

Comment: And then same with `terraform show -json`?

Comment: terraform state list returns that error 'Failed to load state: state snapshot was created by Terraform v0.14.5, which is newer than current v0.13.0'

Comment: same with terraform show -json

Comment: if I upgrade terraform to 0.14.5 (using tfenv) and run terraform state list it returns nothing. Running terraform show -json also just returns {"format_version":"0.1"}

Comment: if this is an issue, I can upgrade straight to 0.14 and from there further versions, however it was my understanding that terraform recommends upgrading step by step so from 0.12 to 0.13 and so on. Is this the case or is it safe to upgrade to v14 from v12?

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: s3 with dynamoDB

Answer (score 2):

Terraform is holding its state either in a remote backend or in a local one.

If you have no configuration that looks like this in your configuration files, minding that the backend type might differ based on the one used, so the name in `"..."` might vary:

```hcl
terraform {
  backend "..." { 
  }
}
```

Then it would be safe to assume you have a local JSON state file named *terraform.tfsate*, and also, since your project existed before the upgrade, a file *terraform.tfsate.backup*.

If you peak into those files, you will see the version of terraform used to create the said state in the beginning of the file.

For example:

```json
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "0.14.5",
}
```

From there, and with all the caution in the world, ensuring you indeed didn't change anything in the remote state, you have some options:

1. if your file *terraform.tfsate.backup* still have `"terraform_version": "0.13.0"`, you could just make a rollback by removing the *terraform.tfsate* and renaming *terraform.tfsate.backup* to *terraform.tfsate*
2. you can try to "hack" into the actual *terraform.tfsate* and change the version there by adapting the line `"terraform_version": "0.14.5"`
3. As advised in the below link, you could [create a state version using the API](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041299873), so, overriding the state by manually specifying your expected version `terraform_version`

My advise still, would be to make a `diff` of *terraform.tfsate* against *terraform.tfsate.backup* to see what have possibly changed, or use a versioning tool if your *terraform.tfsate* is under version control.

*Useful read: https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001147287-Downgrading-Terraform-Version-in-the-State*

Comment: sorry yeah, it is using backend not local. However, when logging into the console and seeing the state file, the last change was my last update (over a year ago) and not today. And it still shows 0.12 in the file - so how can this be? What is this state snapshot if it hasn't changed the remote state?

Comment: ok for me it was a `dependency` in terragrunt that was in higher version.